# Showing overlay on sidebar menu open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show an overlay when then sidebar menu opens.
And close the menu when the overlay is clicked.

here is what i've done:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
      $('#overlay').toggle();
    });

    $('#overlay').click(function() {
      $('#overlay').hide('200');
      $('#wrapper').removeClass('toggled');
    });
  });


#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

here is the demo - https://jsbin.com/vasisedoha/edit?css,js,output

my code is working fine.

I'm stuck at making the animation look good. Please help me fix the animation effect.

I want android lollipop, material design type effect.

Answer (score 6):

Try the below,

You can use jQuery `fadeIn` and `fadeToggle` functions

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
      $('#overlay').fadeToggle( "slow", "swing" );
    });

    $('#overlay').click(function() {
      $('#overlay').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#wrapper').removeClass('toggled');
    });

  });
```

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

body {padding-top: 51px;}
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>





<div class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top'>
<div class='navbar-header'>
<button class='navbar-toggle pull-left' data-toggle='collapse' id='menu-toggle' type='button'>
<span class='icon-bar'></span>
<span class='icon-bar'></span>
<span class='icon-bar'></span>
</button>
<a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>Simple Sidebar</a>
</div>
</div>
 <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <div id='overlay'></div>
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
```